# Several buttons on one form calling same function

Tags: jquery

trying to develop web form using jquery.

all i need is to have several (don't know how many) buttons on one form.

all of those buttons have to call one same function, and to pass one parameter to that function. that function have to do some post method, but i can handle it.

so, my main problem is that i don't know how to develop JS that will call specific jquery function.

can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you can give a common class to all the links and do something like this

A sample HTML

```
<a class="yourclass" param1="value1" href=#">Text</a>
```

Now the script

```
$(".yourclass").click(function() {

var param = $(this).attr('param1');
//now do the remaing

});
```

Comment: tnx, but in this case, how can i pass parameter to jquery function?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery function ([`jQuery` or `$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)) to find the buttons using nearly any [CSS3 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/) (and some [special jQuery ones](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), like [`:button`](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) — shout out to ["just somebody"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036927/several-buttons-on-one-form-calling-same-function/3036942#3036942) for that), and then use the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function to hook up a handler, like this:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(event) {
    // Here, `this` is the raw DOM element for the button.
    // You can use $(this) to get a jQuery wrapper for it.
});
```

`click` is just shorthand for [`bind('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

In terms of "passing" a value into the handler, you can do that by having the event call a function that has the value coded into it, like this:

```
$(':button').click(function(event) {
    // Here, `this` is the raw DOM element for the button.
    // You can use $(this) to get a jQuery wrapper for it.
    doSomethingNifty("foo");
    return false; // Do this if you want to prevent the default action
});
function doSomethingNifty(arg) {
    alert(arg);
}
```

Now any button on the page will show an alert saying "foo".

Finally: If you want to prevent the default action of the button (if it has one), return `false` from the handler, as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':button').bind('click', myfun);
```